# Which binaries should I go for JWT for java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jwt

I am the novice to JWT token usage, while reading came to know from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) that there are six versions with different types of binaries are available as below.

1. com.auth0 / java-jwt / 3.3.0
2. org.bitbucket.b_c / jose4j / 0.6.3
3. com.nimbusds / nimbus-jose-jwt / 5.7
4. io.jsonwebtoken / jjwt / 0.9.0
5. com.inversoft / prime-jwt / 1.3.0
6. io.vertx / vertx-auth-jwt / 3.5.1

Can anyone please explain to me what is the broad difference between them, except java version support.

Comment: They're just different implementations of the same thing. In this situation, I'd usually go with the one which is most widely used. According to Maven Central, that's either Nimbus or jjwt. Take your pick!

Answer (score 5):

A [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) can be cryptographically *signed* (making it a [JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515)) or *encrypted* (making it a [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)):

[image: JWT, JWS and JWE]
<sup>The image was extracted from this [page](https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3).</sup>

Take your pick based on the features supported by each implementation. As mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170904/which-binaries-should-i-go-for-jwt-for-java/50171972#comment87359296_50170904), *JJWT* and *Nimbus JOSE + JWT* seem to be the most widely used libraries for JWT in Java.

The key difference between them is the JWE support (which is only supported by *Nimbus JOSE + JWT* as of May 2018).

See the documentation for details on usage and supported features of both libraries:

- [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) documentation on GitHub
- [Nimbus JOSE + JWT](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/wiki/Home) documentation on BitBucket

Comment: I think now Jose4j has also got the support for JWE. Please check https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home